How can I fix coefplot() error "need finite 'ylim' values"
I'm not 100% sure this is a coding issue, let me know.
I'm trying to plot the coefficients of this DiD model using fake data, but I'm not savvy enough to know if it's a problem coefplot() or if it's that my model, feols(...), is misspecified.
Any ideas?
EDIT: I did notice just now that the y values are NaN in feols(...) call, maybe that is the issue? The estimates seem good, so I'm still not sure what this implies.
library(fixest)
library(dplyr)

# Create fake data
fake_data <- tibble(
  state = c(rep("c",10), rep("t",10)),
  time = c(1:10,1:10),
  treat = c(rep(0,15), 1,1,1,1,1),
  y = c(seq(9,36,3), seq(11,23,3), 28,31,34,37,40)
  ) |> 
  mutate(state = factor(state, levels = c("t","c"))) |> 
  mutate(y = c(seq(9,36,3), seq(11,23,3), 28,31+2,34+4,37+6,40+8))

Data looks like:
# A tibble: 20 × 4
   state  time treat     y
   <fct> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 c         1     0     9
 2 c         2     0    12
 3 c         3     0    15
 4 c         4     0    18
 5 c         5     0    21
 6 c         6     0    24
 7 c         7     0    27
 8 c         8     0    30
 9 c         9     0    33
10 c        10     0    36
11 t         1     0    11
12 t         2     0    14
13 t         3     0    17
14 t         4     0    20
15 t         5     0    23
16 t         6     1    28
17 t         7     1    33
18 t         8     1    38
19 t         9     1    43
20 t        10     1    48

Model seems to work:

feols(y ~ i(time, state, ref = 5) | 
        state + time, 
      data = data_mult_t_dyn) |>  
  etable(vcov = "iid") 

                      feols(y ~ i(t..
Dependent Var.:                     y
                                     
time = 1 x state = t  -1.95e-14 (NaN)
time = 2 x state = t  -1.33e-14 (NaN)
time = 3 x state = t   -1.6e-14 (NaN)
time = 4 x state = t   -1.6e-14 (NaN)
time = 6 x state = t      2.000 (NaN)
time = 7 x state = t      4.000 (NaN)
time = 8 x state = t      6.000 (NaN)
time = 9 x state = t      8.000 (NaN)
time = 10 x state = t     10.00 (NaN)
Fixed-Effects:        ---------------
state                             Yes
time                              Yes
_____________________ _______________
S.E. type             NA (not-avail.)
Observations                       20
R2                                  1
Within R2                           1
---
Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

I can't plot the coefficients:

test <- feols(y ~ i(time, state, ref = 5) | 
                state + time, 
              data = data_mult_t_dyn) 


coefplot(summary(test))
coefplot(test)

Output:
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values

